# Is there M2_HOME analog for sbt?

Tags: java, scala, maven, sbt

For maven I can create M2_HOME system variable and any tool or IDE which use maven can easy detect where it is stored. How to specify sbt folder via system variables? Is there M2_HOME analog for sbt?

Comment: It used to be SBT_HOME, but I cannot find it in the docs. Does it work for you? Regards

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to set it using the system property `sbt.global.base`, with SBT 0.13.x you can set that in env variables `JAVA_OPTS` or `SBT_OPTS`, a file called `.sbtopts` in the directory you run sbt in, the global `sbtopts` file (`/usr/local/etc/sbtopts` on my machine, guess it depends on where you put sbt) or with command line parameters like this:

```
sbt -Dsbt.global.base=/somewhere/.sbt
```

Edit:

Also, the command line parameter -sbt-dir

Comment: But it [points to](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Command-Line-Reference.html) settings and plugins directory, not sbt it selft globally.

Comment: Ah, sorry, so long since I used maven that I remembered wrongly that M2_HOME points to where it reads it settings and puts it cache. Looking at the starter script from SBT 0.13 I can find no such option. (also since it might even download the required sbt version jar depending on the project the concept of a HOME is a bit unfitting)